# conditional awk statement to create a new field with additive value

Tags: dataframe, awk

**Question**
How would I use awk to create a new field that has $2+consistent value?
I am planning to cycle through a list of values but I wouldn't mind using a one liner for each command

**PseudoCode**

```
awk '$1 == Bob {$4 = $2 + 400}' file
```

**Sample Data**

```
Philip  13  2
Bob  152   8
Bob  4561  2
Bob  234  36
Bob  98  12
Rey  147  152
Rey  15   1547
```

**Expected Output**

```
Philip  13  2
Bob  152   8  408
Bob  4561  2  402
Bob  234  36  436
Bob  98  12   412
Rey  147  152
Rey  15   1547
```

Comment: awk does not automatically print, you have to tell it to.

Comment: an unquoted string it treated as a variable, and an uninitialized variable is treated as an empty string or the number zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just quote Bob, also you want to add third field not second

```
$ awk '$1=="Bob" {$4=$3+400}1' file | column -t

Philip  13    2
Bob     152   8     408
Bob     4561  2     402
Bob     234   36    436
Bob     98    12    412
Rey     147   152
Rey     15    1547
```

Answer (score 2):

Here , check if `$1` is equal to Bob and , reconstruct the record (`$0`) by appending `$2 FS 400` in to `$0`. Here `FS` is the field separator used between 3rd and 4th fields. `1` in the end means tell awk to take the default action which is print.

```
awk '$1=="Bob"{$0=$0 FS $2 + 400}1' file
Philip  13  2
Bob  152   8 552
Bob  4561  2 4961
Bob  234  36 634
Bob  98  12 498
Rey  147  152
Rey  15   1547
```

Or , if you want to keep name(Bob) as variable

```
awk -vname="Bob" '$1==name{$0=$0 FS $2 + 400}1' file
```

Comment: wow, that was really simple. do you mind explaining what the 1 does that the end of the line?

Answer (score 2):

***1st solutiuon:*** Could you please try following too once. I am using here `NF` and `NF+1` `awk`'s out of the box variables. Where `$NF` denotes value of last column of current line and `$(NF+1)` will create an additional column if condition of `st field string`Bob` is found is TRUE.

```
awk '{$(NF+1)=$1=="Bob"?400+$NF:""} 1' OFS="\t" Input_file
```

***2nd solution:*** In case we don't want to create a new field and simply want to print the values as per condition then try following, this should be more faster I believe.

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"}{$1=$1;print $0,$1=="Bob"?400+$NF:""}' Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
Philip  13      2   
Bob     152     8      408
Bob     4561    2      402
Bob     234     36     436
Bob     98      12     412
Rey     147     152 
Rey     15      1547
```

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation for above code now.

```
awk '                                 ##Starting awk program here.
{
  $(NF+1)=$1=="Bob"?400+$NF:""        ##Creating a new last field here whose value will be depending upon condition check.
                                      ##its checking condition if 1st field is having Bob string in it then add 400 value to last field value or make it NULL.
}
1                                     ##awk works on method of condition then action. so by mentioning 1 making condition TRUE here and NO action defined so by default print of current line will happen.
' OFS="\t"  Input_file                ##Setting OFS as TAB here where OFS ois output field separator and mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: @serious, could you please check this one once and let me know?